# Swipe up and swipe down the viewController when user tap on ViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Two viewControllers one is aboutViewController and second one is customViewController.Added customViewController in aboutViewController as an subView on bottom position now I want when user swipe up the whole controller swipe up and show all the content of viewController and swipe down to get the same position through animation.

AboutViewController:

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customsController:CustomViewController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        customController()
    }
    
    func customController(){
        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: CustomViewController.self)) as? CustomViewController else {return}
        let screnSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let frame:CGRect = .init(x: 0, y: screnSize.height - 300, width: screnSize.width, height: 300)
        vc.view.frame = frame
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the example I want to achieve like this one see the pics below
[image: see second controller on bottom position]
[image: when user swipe up the whole controlller swipe up]
I want this functionality

Comment: Could you show some code you tried ?

Comment: I already shown see the above pics in about viewcontroller I'm calling the custom controller as an subview now I want when user swip up the whole view controller swipe up and when user swipe down the whole custom controller came to an original position like in most riding apps.

Comment: Ok, show the code that you have written to try to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Check the code  please i've attached the code just added the customController in aboutViewController  and customcontroller on the bottom position you can see .Just only want when user swipe on customController the whole controller swipe up and when user swipe down the customcontroller goes to its perivious position